# Creating Date Partitioned Tables programmatically

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io

Is there a way to create a date partitioned table using `Apache Beam BigQueryIO`, in other words, is there a way to use partition decorator for a table which is not created yet?

I know that I can create a table at first and then I can use partition decorator within my code but since I dynamically determine the `TableDestination` from fields of rows, I cannot create these tables in advance.

My code is like this:

```
rows.apply("Write rows",
    BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
      .to(new SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, TableDestination>() {
          @Override
          public TableDestination apply(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> value) {
            TableRow t = value.getValue();

            String tableName = ... // get from the fields of table row
            String partition = ... // get the date part that will be used for decorator

            TableDestination td = new TableDestination(
                      "project-id:dataset-id." + tableName + "$" + partition, "");
              return td;
          }
      }).withSchema(someSchema)
      .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

With this, it tries to create a table of `project-id:dataset-id.tableName$partition` and it complains that `$` cannot be used inside a table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that this currently is not possible.

There is a request for this in the official BEAM JIRA issue list though:[BEAM-2390](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2390) and [an official pull request](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3266) , so it looks like this is going to be possible soon!

Answer (score 0):

Table id format: `The ID of the table. The ID must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_). The maximum length is 1,024 characters.` check the [BigQuery doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables).

Comment: That `$` sign stands for partition decorator, which is the essence of my question. Normally, if I create a table beforehand, I can use that sign to specify my partition but I cannot use it for a table which is not created yet.